# Почему не работает метод map? В консоле выдает ошибку

Tags: typescript, angular

```
 const deleteColumns: any = {
        cols: editColumns[1].map((column: { id: any }) => {
            return {id: column.id};
        }),
    };
```

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Потому что editColumns[1] равно undefined, убедитесь, что передаёте значение правильно

Comment: Спасибо. Поставил знак вопроса.